# Horizontally center alignment of a span around its parent element

Tags: css, alignment, html

It was a question during the job interview which I had, although we can horizontally align a wrapper div around its parent element such as body by defining the HTML and CSS as follows:

```
#body { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#wrapper { margin: 0 auto; }

<body>
<div id="wrapper">Horizontally Centered Div</div>
</body>
```

but with the span it's not aligning the same way.

```
#body { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#just-span { margin: 0 auto; }

<body>
<span id="just-span">Horizontally Centered Span</span>
</body>
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

For span element which has display: inline; default value, use

```
text-align: center;
```

to its parent css declaration. Check here http://jsfiddle.net/7njAf/1/.

Comment: Thanks, it really works! Btw why you gave position: relative to that span and moved top 100px instead of just giving a margin-top 100px and no position relative.

Answer (score 2):

Your span lacks the "wrapper" id in your span and thus the css isn't being applied.

**Update**

The span element is by default display: inline, which does not appear to accept margins.  You can see this by adding display:block; to the just-span css

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to edit the span id here on my question, now you can read it.

Comment: @Lightcoder updated my answer it appears to be due to the default styling of span tags